# Place a link at top AND bottom of each node

Tags: 7, nodes

I made some code to put a button/link at the bottom of a node. But it would be nice to place this link also at the top of the node. Would this be possible?

This is the code that places a button at the bottom of each node:

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $node->content['links']['job'] = array(
        '#links' => array(
            array(
                'title' => t('Apply'),
                'href' => 'jobs/apply',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing your link in the links object of the $content array which will generally, unless a template file overrides it, render all it's content in one place.

If the one link you have added visually covers your needs, the other one should be placed within the $content array, with a 'light' #weight property (0 for instance) along with the rest of the array's items (body, fields, etc).

the code could look something like this:

```
$node->content['top_link'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<a href="jobs/apply" class="jobs apply">'.t('Apply').'</a>',
  '#weight' => 0,
   );
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer, thank you very much. Simple and easy, but very usefull to me!